# MYSQL Transactions using BasicDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, database, transactions

I am using Apache BasicDataSource to handle my database code - simply i just create methods to do particular tasks that access the database. An example can be seen below;

```
/**
 * Update a users display name
 * @param userid the user id to update for
 * @param displayName the display name to change too
 * @return true if update suceeded 
 */
public static boolean updateDisplayName(String userid, String displayName){
    Connection conn = null;
    String sql = "update UserAccount set displayname = ? where userid = ? ";

    try {
        conn = source.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1,displayName);
        st.setString(2,userid);
        st.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("An error occured when updating the display name for " + userid, e);
    } finally{
        closeConnection(conn);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have had a google around and can't seem to find any examples of how to use transactions. Please could someone advise me on how this might be done?

Thanks

Comment: But why would you need a transaction in this particular code? It's only one `UPDATE`..

Comment: just saying in general, i should have pasted a better example but just wanted to illustrate how i currently do things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take the connection mark this connection as auto commit false

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Once you succesfuly done your task commit that transaction

```
connection.commit();
```

In case of exception rollback that transaction

```
connection.rollback();
```

It is normal jdbc transaction you can go with other implementation of transaction as well
 .. Check this example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)